# Public properties in a class

Tags: c#, class, oop, properties

I have two public properties in a class. The business requirement is one property to be exactly the copy of the other one.

How can I have one of the properties to point to the other one?
I want ProductNumebr to be the same as SKU.

```
private string _sku;
public string Sku
{
            get
            {
                return _sku;
            }
            set
            {
                this._sku = value;
            }
}

private string _productNumber;    
public string ProductNumber 
{
             get
             {
                return _sku ?? string.Empty;
             }
             set
             {
                 this._productNumber = Sku;
             }
  }
```

Comment: You can use the same backing field in both properties, If `_productNumber` is not being used internally in code for setting values. The business requirement you mentioned is just not enough to provide a good logical suggestion.

Comment: ProductNumber has been used in an application but the new requirement is without touching the code on the UI point ProductNumber to SKU.

Comment: What language is this? Please add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 2):

Well, It's completely depends on Usage of new SKU property. Whether you want these two properties in sync (Which I guess should be) or SKU has to be Read-only and only used for getting ProductNumber.

You can simply use one backing field for both properties.

```
string _productNumber; 

public string Sku
{
            get
            {
                return _productNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                this._productNumber= value;
            }
}

public string ProductNumber 
{
            get
            {
                return _productNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                this._productNumber= value;
            }
  }
```

This could be a hacky solution but this way you can keep the Read and write in sync on duplicate properties of an object in *single threaded* environment.

Comment: I don't think this is a _hacky_ solution at all — this is _the_ solution (given what we know) where Sku is just an alias for ProductNumber. Or, alternatively given _"the new requirement is without touching the code on the UI point ProductNumber to SKU"_ turn it around so ProductNumber is an alias for Sku.

Comment: After that change, when I am running the following query, the ProductNumebr is still pointing to ProductNumber and not SKU.

Comment: products = (from p in this._productRepository.Table
                            orderby p.Id
                            where !p.Deleted &&
                            p.ProductNumber.Contains("K01")
                            select p).ToList();

Comment: If these two properties are copy of each other then keeping single backing field will work in any case. I think you are looking for a case when SKU can have value other than ProductNumber. Is it the case?

Comment: ProductNumber will be null, so whenever they are pointing to ProductNumber, I want to get the SKU value.

Comment: That means if ProductNumber is null you want to return SKU Right? Is it true for vice versa too?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, ProductNumber has value or not, I want to return SKU value. So no more ProductNumber value will be used.

Answer (score 0):

if i correctly understand , you mean there's an integration that accepts the table object that has sku and ProductNumber fileds and its source is closed but you know it just sets value to sku field and the table objects source is closed too
so you can just create an object of the table and pass it to the integration .

but in this procedure ProductNumebr wont be set . so you want to mimic the sku and then set ProductNumebr according to the sku .

i think if i understand what you mean correct , you have to use polymorphisms to handle this situation , create an object of mimic and pass it to the integration :

```
class mimic:(the table class name)
{
   (the table class name) tbl = new (the table class name)() ;
   new public string sku
   {
      get
      {
         return tbl.sku ;
      }
      set
      {
         tbl.sku = value ;
         tbl.ProductNumber = value ?? string.Empty ;
      }
   }

  new public string ProductNumber
   {
      get
      {
         return tbl.ProductNumber ;
      }
       //no need to set because as you said it wont set the productNumber
   }

   //get the origin table object and set it to its right place for further processes

   public (the table class name) getTheOrigin()
   {
      return this.tbl
   }
}
```